# datetime to date format in python

Tags: python, datetime

I Have a value of

`datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 28, 13, 53, 36)`

and I want it to be printed as string as

`Wednesday, January 28, 2015 13:53:36`

I tried to

`import datetime
x = datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 28, 13, 53, 36)
z = strptime(str(x), '%A, %B %d, %Y %H:%M:%S')`

but got:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#40>", line 1, in <module>
    z = strptime(str(x), '%A, %B %d, %Y %H:%M:%S')
NameError: name 'strptime' is not defined`

does anyone have an idea about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your import - the correct form of accessing `strptime` is `datetime.datetime.strptime` (parsing a string to a date) - but it doesn't look like you want that, instead you're after `datetime.datetime.strftime` (formats a date to a string).

Ultimately though, Python's datetime object has custom string formatting which can be accessed via `str.format` and will save a bit of typing, eg:

```
>>> dt = datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 28, 13, 53, 36)
>>> format(dt, '%A, %B %d, %Y %H:%M:%S')
'Wednesday, January 28, 2015 13:53:36'
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the date method:

```
datetime.datetime.date()
```

You should use datetime.datetime.strptime:

```
import datetime

dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(string_date, fmt)
```